# How do I transfer records from one table to another?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following example table:

```
class DestDB(Base):
    __tablename__ = "dest_db"
    __table_args__ = (Index('nameplace', "name", "place"))

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100))
    place = Column(String(100))
```

I'm quite used to using a dictionary to add records. For example:

```
dict = {"name": "foo", "place": "bar"}
session.add(DestDB(**dict))
```

However, how do I transfer records from one table to another? I presume I could query the source table, iterate through each record converting it into a dictionary and then add the result as above. However, I'm sure there must be a neater solution?

There will be duplicate combinations of `name` and `place` records in the source database so I don't want to use any kind of bulk operation unless it won't insert any duplicate records.

Let's assume the source database looks like this:

```
class SourceDB(Base):
    __tablename__ = "source_db"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100))
    place = Column(String(100))
```

I only want to transfer the `name` and `place` fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest sticking to **The Zen of Python**.

*Explicit is better than implicit.*

I'd implement a method on ‍`SourceDB` to provide the dictionary format of the object as I want it.

```
class SourceDB(Base):
    __tablename__ = "source_db"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100))
    place = Column(String(100))

    def as_dict(self):
        return dict(name=self.name, place=self.place)
```

and use it like this

```
session.add(DestDB(**src_obj.as_dict()))
```

Although you could do it more dynamically, I'd still recommend the more explicit way.

```
class SourceDB(Base):
    __tablename__ = "source_db"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(100))
    place = Column(String(100))

    def as_dict(self, fields):
        return dict(field: getattr(self, field) for field in fields if hasattr(self, field))
```

and doing this

```
session.add(DestDB(src_obj.as_dict(("name", "place"))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to confirm; you'd recommend the first way, i.e. ```return dict(name=self.name, place=self.place)```?

Comment: You're welcome. Exactly. It's simple, explicit, and easy to read.

Comment: Ok - just started to implement this in the real database and I'm stumped with actually how to use the above method. I only want to transfer some of the records in ```SourceDB``` - how would I do that? I presume I need to iterate through the table in some way like I would have done with a query?

Comment: Yup. you'd want to query the `SourceDB` and iterate through the records you want to transfer and create a new record in `DestDB`.

Comment: Awesome - just figured it out!! Might even be starting to get a handle on OOP. However, the problem I've just run into is that ```name``` and ```place``` don't have the same name in ```SourceDB``` as in ```DestDB``` :( Thinking ahead there will be a few times I'll need to repeat this and each time the field names will be slightly different. I presume that means I can't explode(?) using ```**```? If that's the case then would it be simpler to iterate through the query and create dictionaries on the fly without a dedicated method? Otherwise I'd need a specific method for each field name combo?

Comment: I could update the question if that might make this chain more readable?

Comment: In this case, I'd recommend creating dictionaries on the fly. I think the problem you're solving doesn't concern `SourceDB`. So adding this kinds of method violates the **separation of concerns**.

Comment: FYI - I'll mark the answer as accepted since it answers my original question before I changed the game!